# Blender stop responding while texturing

Tags: materials

Im trying to do 3d models with diferent pose but when I texture the 3d model and next I try to move the bones or do something, blender stop responding.Only after texturing. I need help. My PC specs:  AMD Ryzen 5 2600 |   RTX 2060 | 8GB RAM DDR4

Comment: "...try to <random thing> *or something*... only after texturing" is not exactly an accurate explanation. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please), then [this](https://easyblend.org/html/troubleshooting/crash.html), then use the edit link below your question to add relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off the textured view, I notice mine slows down pretty bad when I try to do anything rig related after texturing.